# Get the full path of file name which is numbers only `highest number` , on main Folder or Subfolders?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using database software and export excel files from it and save on my desktop with name like ********.xls
***** means numbers only , for example   08134471.xls
23222578.xls 
Those numbers on file name are random on count and length. 
The path is constant `D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\`    but, file name will change each time incrementally to higher number. 
**So**, I need to open the workbook with `highest number` on the cited path. 
In advance , gratefully for your help.

```
Sub Open_Numeric_File()
 
    Workbooks.Open "D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\08134471.xls"
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the next function. It will return independent of the number name pattern. I mean, being "0002345" or "02346", It processes all files from folder and subfolders:

```
Function getLastFileName(strFold As String, Optional strext As String = "*.*") As String
    Dim arrD, i As Long, lastName As String, lngNb As Long, arrN, El
    'return all files name in an array
    arrD = Filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strext & """ /b /s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")
    For Each El In arrD   'iterate between the array elements
            arrN = Split(El, "\") 'make an array splitting the name by "\"
            'check if the name is numeric:
            If IsNumeric(Split(arrN(UBound(arrN)), ".")(0)) Then
                'compare the lngNb variable (initially 0) with the numeric value:
                If lngNb < CLng(Split(arrN(UBound(arrN)), ".")(0)) Then
                     'addapt lngNb like the bigger number
                     lngNb = CLng(Split(arrN(UBound(arrN)), ".")(0)): lastName = El
                End If
            End If
    Next
    getLastFileName = lastName 'build the necessary path
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testGetLastFileName()
    Debug.Print getLastFileName("D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\", "*.xls*")
End Sub
```

It excludes workbooks name not being a number...

**Edited**:

The next version returns (and process) only the files in the main folder (excluding files in subfolders):

```
Function getLastNumberFile(strFold As String, Optional strext As String = "*.*") As String
    Dim arrD, i As Long, lastName As String, lngNb As Long, El
    'return all files name in an array
    arrD = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strext & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    If UBound(arrD) = -1 Then MsgBox "Nothing could be found in the path you supplied...": Exit Function
    arrD(UBound(arrD)) = "@@##": arrD = Filter(arrD, "@@##", False) 'remove the last (empty) element

    For Each El In arrD   'iterate between the array elements
            If IsNumeric(Split(El, ".")(0)) Then
                'compare the lngNb variable (initially 0) with the numeric value:
                If lngNb < CLng(Split(El, ".")(0)) Then
                     'addapt lngNb like the bigger number
                     lngNb = CLng(Split(El, ".")(0)): lastName = El
                End If
            End If
    Next
    getLastNumberFile = strFold & lastName 'build the necessary path
End Function
```

It can be used simple setting the necessary workbook as:

```
  Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(getLastNumberFile("D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\", "*.xls*"))
```

And the next version, able to return for both cases. It uses a trick, splitting a joined array using the separator obtained by concatenation between the folder path and "|". Then removing the last array element (in case of returning without subfolders files):

```
Function getLastFileN(strFold As String, Optional strext As String = "*.*", Optional boolSubfolders = False) As String
    Dim arrD, i As Long, lastName As String, lngNb As Long, arrN, El
    'return all files name in an array
    If boolSubfolders Then 'subfolders included
        arrD = Filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strext & """ /b/s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")
    Else                   'without subfolders
        arrD = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strext & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)
        arrD = Split(strFold & Join(arrD, "|" & strFold), "|")  'add the folder path to the file names
        arrD(UBound(arrD)) = "@@##": arrD = Filter(arrD, "@@##", False) 'remove the last (empty) array element
    End If

    For Each El In arrD           'iterate between the array elements
            arrN = Split(El, "\") 'make an array splitting the name by "\"
            'check if the name is numeric:
            If IsNumeric(Split(arrN(UBound(arrN)), ".")(0)) Then
                'compare the lngNb variable (initially 0) with the numeric value:
                If lngNb < CLng(Split(arrN(UBound(arrN)), ".")(0)) Then
                     'addapt lngNb like the bigger number
                     lngNb = CLng(Split(arrN(UBound(arrN)), ".")(0)): lastName = El
                End If
            End If
    Next
    getLastFileN = lastName
End Function
```

Comment: @user22 I though  it is not complicated to be understood... And I made the testing sub only to show how it can be checked. I will place some comments. Not right now, in some  minutes...

Comment: `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(getLastFileName("D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\", "*.xls*"))`

Comment: @user22 Well, the above function uses `DOS` `Dir` command which, for folders and subfolders, returns the whole path. Only for files in the folder it returns only the files name. I will adapt the function for such a situation. It can be also adapted to return for both cases, but it is a little more complicated. I will adapt the above code to return processing only the file in the main folder, not subfolders. In fact, i will add another code. Maybe, somebody else will need it as it is...

Comment: My feedback, supposing **Desktop** is the `main folder` with file name 123.xlsx and **SubF** is the subfolder with file name 55555.xlsx.
Code in all tests `debug.Print Function_Name("D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\", "*.xls*")`.
**Function(2)** works correctly as supposed on main folder only. **Function(3)** although it is same concept like function(1), but works on main folder only and correctly.
**Function(1)** `initial answer` it works strangely, it fetch the file name but parent folder is missing on the path , as this `D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\55555.xlsx` **SubF** is missing on the path.

Comment: @user22 Please test the adapted functions. Not tested, adapted on mobile phone... I will have access to a computer only after some hours. But the logic of modification should make them working, I think.

Comment: Now, Functions (1) and (2) works correctly  , But **Function (3)** not works well, output is strange path `D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\123.xlsx`.
I think functions 1 & 2 are enough for both cases. grateful for your help.

Comment: I will solve the third one when I will be able to work on a computer...

Comment: @user22 Please, test the last adapted function. It should also work as it should.

Comment: @user22 1. The last function parameter (`boolSubfolders`) should be elocvent, I think. If you call the function without it, or with it `False`, it should return from the main fodder. If you call it with the last (third) parameter as `True`, it will return from folder and subfolders. 2. I would dare to say that this is not a bug... Theoretically, the function can be adapted to deal with that, but you should check that (using `Dir`) if you consider that the path may not be correct. What about sending a shape to the function? Or a picture full name, a form, a sheet etc? Not the object of OP...

Comment: @user22 I adapted the function in discussion to send a message in case of a wrong folder path, or if no files with the specific extension have been found. But you must know that the other two functions will behave similarly in case of such way of using... I mean, they will raise an error. I never needed such functions. I created them, strictly based on the requirements in your question.

Comment: It has been design to return choosing from a folder and its subfolders a number, extracted form the files name. So, such numbers must exist. I mentioned after the (first) function: **It excludes workbooks name not being a number...** If no any file containing a  number in its name, it should return **an empty string**. I cannot imagine in which circumstances `lastName` may take a value **if not allocated in the loop**, where the code does not jump. If you have a reproductible example I can look at it and try understanding what happens...

Comment: FYI, I found this line `arrD = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").Exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strext & """ /b").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf)` has a problem with unicode files name e,g `Arabic`  (I am not sure if Romanian language is unicode or not) , the returned unicode names is distorted like `êéه م© î.xlsx`(this is not Arabic letters at all).

Answer (score 1):

Something for you to consider:

```
Sub OpenAndCalc()

Dim myDir As String, fn As String, high As String, highVal As Long

    myDir = "D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\"
    fn = Dir(myDir & "*.xls")
    
    Do While fn <> "" And Not fn Like "*[!0-9]*.xls"
        If Val(fn) > highVal Then highVal = Val(fn): high = fn
        fn = Dir()
    Loop

    Workbooks.Open myDir & high
    
End Sub
```

This should:

- Loop through all '.xls' files in your static directory;
- Test if anything before '.xls' is numeric through `Like()`;
- Test the numeric substring, using `Val()`, against previous (or empty) value;
- Append the static directory with the highest value and open this workbook.

Comment: I have one xls file on desktop with name 22.xls. After I tried your edited answer I got this error     `Run-time error '1004':
Sorry, we couldn't find D:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\00000022.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?`
Your first answer working better than this answer

Comment: @user22, I edited the answer because I saw you had leading zero's in the file-names. Do you actually have leading zero's? The error has to do with that since I append leading zeros to match the length of 8 digits as per your samples.

Comment: @user22, I edited the answer to make sure you can have any arbitrairy length of numbers including leading zero's.

Comment: But, I said on my question that `Those numbers on file name are random on count and length` and it can starts without zero

Comment: @user22, did you test the edited answer?

Comment: Yes, I tested your last edited answer.
It works first but `If I renamed the file (also numeric)` and run code again ,I got **Run-time error '1004': file not found  possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? **.
I chose the other answer from “FaneDure” because it has not that issue.

Comment: Strange but good thing you found a working answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a list of all of the files in the folder, put them into a sheet / array and then sort them by the file name

There's a really good piece of code below that came from VBATips

```
Dim iRow

Sub ListFiles()
    iRow = 11
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("C7"), Range("C8"))
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders)
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        iCol = 2
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This will list all of the files in the folder into Excel, you could change the to an array

After this, just sort them on the myFile.DateLastModified

Sorry this isn't a full answer, had a minute free and thought this might help you

Partial Source:
http://excelexperts.com/VBA-Tips-List-Files-In-A-Folder

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this:

Uses the VBA `Dir()` function to loop over all the .xls files (not directories etc) in a folder. It splits out the text in front off the ".", and attempts to convert this into a number, while keeping a track of the maximum number found.

If on a 32-bit system replace `LongLong` with `Long`, and `CLngLng` with `CLng`.

```
Sub ListFiles()
    Dim llFile As LongLong
    Dim llMax As LongLong
    Dim strFileToOpen As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\*.xls"
    strFile = Dir(strPath, vbNormal)
       
    On Error Resume Next
    
    While Len(strFile) > 0
        llFile = 0
        llFile = CLngLng(Split(strFile, ".")(0))
        If llFile > 0 And llFile > llMax Then
            llMax = llFile
            strFileToOpen = strFile
        End If
               
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend

    On Error Goto 0
    
    If Len(strFileToOpen) > 0 Then Workbooks.Open (strPath & "\" & strFileToOpen)
End Sub
```

Comment: My office is 32bit on windows 10 x64.I replaced the required words ( LongLong & CLngLng )
But your code not works at all and no error raised.

Comment: Maybe just hard-code your directory path, rather than use the environment variable ... Unfortunately I don't have a desktop full of files with numbers in the name ...